# Computing $\frac{\partial(X^Tb)}{\partial X}$

Tags: matrix-calculus

In the matrix cookbook there is an identity $$\frac{\partial (a^TX^T b)}{\partial X} = ba^T$$

I recently ran into a problem where I had to compute $$\frac{\partial (X^T b)}{\partial X}$$

but I couldn't find a formula for this. However it seems that, at least for my example,

$$\frac{\partial (X^T b)}{\partial X} = b$$.

Does this formula hold in general?

Does it even make sense to take the derivative $$\frac{\partial (X^T b)}{\partial X}$$.

The problem where this came up was chapter 3.1.5 of Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning specifically taking the derivative wrt W of 3.33:

$$ln(p(T|X,W,\beta))=\frac{NK}{2}ln(\frac{\beta}{2\pi}) - \frac{\beta}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N || t_n -W^T \phi (x_n)||^2$$ where I used the chain rule to compute:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial W}ln(p(T|X,W,\beta))=- \frac{\beta}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial W}(t_n -W^T \phi (x_n))^T(t_n -W^T \phi (x_n)) $$

$$=- \frac{\beta}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial (t_n-W^T \phi (x_n))}(t_n -W^T \phi (x_n))^T(t_n -W^T \phi (x_n))\frac{\partial}{\partial W} (t_n-W^T \phi (x_n)) $$

Then I used $$\frac{\partial (x^Tx)}{\partial x}=2x$$ and to compute the derivative

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial W} (t_n-W^T \phi (x_n))$$ I used

$$\frac{\partial (X^T b)}{\partial X} = b$$

which seems to give the correct results.

Furthermore a proof in a similar vein to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2916513/280789) seems to work. Although I'm not sure if this is valid.

Comment: This seems possibly relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2044191/280789

Comment: Be careful that for the first formula to make sense (the one with $a^T X^Tb$), you need $X$ to be a matrix, while for the second (the one you are asking to prove) $X$ is a vector

Comment: @SolubleFish Why does $X$ need to be a vector in the second formula?

Comment: Because if $X$ is a matrix and $b$ a vector, then $f(X) = X^Tb$ is a vector value function, therefore the gradient $\nabla_Xf$ is a $(2,1)$-tensor, which cannot be equal to $b$

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is much clearer to think of the derivative as a linearization of the map
$$
F\colon \mathbb R^{m\times n} \to \mathbb R^n,\, X\mapsto X^T b.
$$
Indeed since
$$
F(X+V)=(X+V)^Tb = X^Tb+V^Tb=F(X)+V^Tb
$$
we find that
$$
D_XF(V)=\frac{\partial (X^Tb)}{\partial X}(V)=V^Tb.
$$

With this there is no need for partial derivatives or writing out the matrices at play. Generally, this definition of the derivative ([See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative)) is often helpful in similar settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this formula is true.
Assuming $X\in\mathbb R^n$ and $b\in\mathbb R^n$, we obtain
$$X^T b = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i b_i.$$

The partial derivative of this linear combination with respect to $X_k$ is $b_k$, which proves your formula:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial(X^T b)}{\partial X} = b.
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm asking for the case where $X$ is a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, so $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $X^Tb \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The derivative $\frac{\partial X^Tb}{\partial X}$ has $n \times m \times n$ terms, so it would be helpful to compute each $\frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X}$ separately:

$$\frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X_{11}} & \frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X_{12}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X_{1n}} \\
\frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X_{21}} & \frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X_{22}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X_{2n}} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X_{m1}} & \frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}
{\partial X_{m2}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X_{mn}} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

If we compute for each element:

$$\frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X_{ij}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} \sum_{l = 1}^{m}X^T_{kl}b_l = \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} \sum_{l = 1}^{m}X_{lk}b_l = \begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $k \ne j$} \\
b_i & \text{if $k = j$}
\end{cases}$$

So the columns of matrix are all zero except $k$th one:

$$\frac{\partial (X^Tb)_k}{\partial X} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & b_1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & b_m & \cdots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

As you mentioned, in this example the results are correct if we take simply $\frac{\partial X^Tb}{\partial X} = b$, but *that's not guaranteed to find a vector answer for every derivative of vector w.r.t. matrix*.

To prevent dealing with tensors, I recommend to not use chain rule and calculate each element of the main derivative separately.